# Syntax error: Unknown word (8:3) pls solve this error in react JS

Tags: css, reactjs

Here is my css file(react js)

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;\
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(7,27,82,1) 0%, rgba(0,128,128,1) 100%),

}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

Pls anyone help as I am a beginner in react js

```
./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
Syntax error: Unknown word (8:3) webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   7 |   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;\
>  8 |   background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(7,27,82,1) 0%, rgba(0,128,128,1) 100%),
     |   ^
   9 | 
  10 | }***strong text***
```

This error occurred during the build time     I am getting this error

Comment: You have a slash at the end of this line: `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;`